# How to estimate the extracted size of a tar.gz file without extracting it in PowerShell 7 (Windows 11)?

Tags: powershell, gzip, tar

I have a tar.gz file that is about 1.39GB. I want to estimate the unzipped size before I actually extract it to avoid filling up my disk. This is for my work and I can only use my work PC (Windows 11) for it. I'm using PowerShell 7. What is the command to accomplish this?

I found many answers under unix/linux, [like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124052/how-can-i-determine-if-running-tar-will-cause-disk-to-fill-up).

I guess in unix/linux, the solve is `tar -cz data_dir | wc -c`

But what is the equivalent in PowerShell 7 (Windows 11)?

Comment: Built-in unfortunately no (for `.tar` specifically). You could however use some library like SharpZipLib that you can download from nuget

Comment: if you're already installing third-party for pwsh 7, just install python instead.  `tarfile` support is builtin

Comment: `tar -cz data_dir | wc -c` is completely wrong, it's for getting the compressed size of a folder instead of getting the original size of a tar.gz archive

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley [Windows 10 build 17063+](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409) already has tar built-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `tar.exe` to list the content of your gzip archive:

```
tar.exe -t -v -f test.tar.gz
```

You can then parse the output and add up the sizes:

```
$tarOutput = tar.exe -t -v -f test.tar.gz
$size = ($tarOutput | %{(-split $_)[4]} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
$size
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a workaround:

```
$tarOutput tar -tvf filename.tar.gz
$totalSize=0
foreach ($line in $tarOutput) {
    $columns = $line -split '\s+', 6
    if ($columns.Length -eq 6) {
        $size = $columns[4]
        if ($size -match '^\d+$') {
            $totalSize += $size
        }
    }
}
$totalSize
```